# How to install and use boost 1.66.0 in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost

I was looking for a tutorial about how to install boost in Visual Studio, but I can't find any. Can you explain the process?

Comment: As mentioned in other answers, the easiest way would be to use VC++ Package Tool or NuGet. The question is incorrectly marked as a duplicate with a link about Visual Studio 2010. The Visual Studio 2010 does not have these possibilities so the answers there are irrelevant.

Comment: @SergeyShandar: Agree, reopened/not a duplicate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way would be [NuGet](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/02/13/find-your-favorite-library-for-c-in-nuget/); the currently available Boost version for VS2017 is indeed 1.66.0

Comment: Can you tell me what to do with NuGet?

Comment: @RafałChrzanowski: StackOverflow doesn't render hyperlinks with underscores, but the word NuGet in my answer is a hyperlink to https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/02/13/find-your-favorite-library-for-c-in-nuget/. There's plenty more to google once you know what tool you need. E.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/package-manager-console

Answer (score 1):

Try the [VC++ Packaging Tool](https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg)  project from Microsoft. I found it very useful and easy to use